# Azure KQL query to get all column names

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

We reached the max column limit (500) of our Log Analytics workspace. To cleanup unnecessary columns I would like to know which columns (and how many) are used for a specific resource provider. I tried extending the following basic query by adding variations with summarize, distinct or count, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider contains "Microsoft.Network"
```

Would this be possible?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: you may want to clarify what `can't seem to make it work` means, in the from of quoting the error message you're getting, and specifying in response to which query it was encountered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no official Azure document which clarifies columns used for a specific resource provider (along with count).

If interested, you may share it as general feedback in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) uservoice or feedback forum and also upvote it and other features that are of interest. In general, Azure feature team would check feasibility of a feature request, triage it, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.

Or else, you may share it as Azure document enhancement feedback by clicking on "This page" option in "Feedback" section at the bottom of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported-export-diagnostic-settings) / [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings) related Azure documents so that the related Azure documents' content author would look on feasibility to enhance the document.